# Boolean column in multicolumn index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, boolean, b-tree

Test table and indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE public.t (id serial, cb boolean, ci integer, co integer)

INSERT INTO t(cb, ci, co) 
SELECT ((round(random()*1))::int)::boolean, round(random()*100), round(random()*100)
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000)

CREATE INDEX "right" ON public.t USING btree (ci, cb, co);
CREATE INDEX wrong ON public.t USING btree (ci, co);
CREATE INDEX right_hack ON public.t USING btree (ci, (cb::integer), co);
```

The problem is that I can't force PostgreSQL to use the "right" index. The next query uses the "wrong" index. It's not optimal because it uses "Filter" (condition: cb = TRUE) and so reads more data from memory (and execution becomes longer):

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE cb = TRUE AND ci = 46 ORDER BY co LIMIT 1000

"Limit  (cost=0.42..4063.87 rows=1000 width=13) (actual time=0.057..4.405 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1960"
"  ->  Index Scan using wrong on t  (cost=0.42..21784.57 rows=5361 width=13) (actual time=0.055..4.256 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (ci = 46)"
"        Filter: cb"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 967"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1960"
"Planning time: 0.318 ms"
"Execution time: 4.530 ms"
```

But when I cast bool column to int, that works fine. This is unclear, because selectivity of both indexes (right and right_hack) remains the same.

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE cb::int = 1 AND ci = 46 ORDER BY co LIMIT 1000

"Limit  (cost=0.42..2709.91 rows=1000 width=13) (actual time=0.027..1.484 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1003"
"  ->  Index Scan using right_hack on t  (cost=0.42..14525.95 rows=5361 width=13) (actual time=0.025..1.391 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((ci = 46) AND ((cb)::integer = 1))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1003"
"Planning time: 0.202 ms"
"Execution time: 1.565 ms"
```

Are there any limitations of using boolean column inside multicolumn index?

Comment: 1000000 rows. I tried analyze, same result

Comment: Indexes have limited value on low-cardinality columns (such as booleans), the amount of work (disk I/O) that they avoid is limited. (and they also add additional work). In some cases, a conditional index (or two) *could* be usefull.

Comment: This index ("right") can use 2 columns ci + cb, so its already is not low-cardinality. And index "right_hack" uses columns with same cardinality. So what the difference?

Answer (score 2):

A conditional index (or two) does seem to work:

```
CREATE INDEX true_bits ON ttt (ci, co)
  WHERE cb = True ;

CREATE INDEX false_bits ON ttt (ci, co)
  WHERE cb = False ;

VACUUM ANALYZE ttt;

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers)
SELECT * FROM ttt
WHERE cb = TRUE AND ci = 46 ORDER BY co LIMIT 1000
        ;
```

---

Plan

```
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.25..779.19 rows=1000 width=13) (actual time=0.024..1.804 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1001
   ->  Index Scan using true_bits on ttt  (cost=0.25..3653.46 rows=4690 width=13) (actual time=0.020..1.570 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (ci = 46)
         Buffers: shared hit=1001
 Planning time: 0.468 ms
 Execution time: 1.949 ms
(7 rows)
```

---

Still, there is very little gain in indexes on low-cardinality columns. The chance that an index-entry can avoid a page-read is very small. For a page size of 8K and a rowsize of ~20, there are ~400 records on a page. There will (almost) always be a *true* record on any page (and a *false* record), so the page will have to be read anyway.

Comment: Question is not about "how make it work". Why it doesn't?. Columns cb and cb::integer have the same cardinality, so why "right_hack" works and "right" doesn't?

Comment: My guess is that there is very little difference between the estimated effort for the different plans. I have been looking for a trace point to show *all* generated plans + their estimates, but could not find it. `SET debug_print_rewritten   = 1;` (and debug_print_plan) come close...

Comment: PostgreSQL can't make an optimal plan in this situation at all. It's easy to check: if you delete the "wrong" index in my example, then PostgreSQL will use the "right" index, but will also use an unnecessary "Filter" by "cb" condition. Looks like PostgreSQL planner's bug.

Comment: Here the index scan on "right" takes ~8ms, the "wrong" index ~4ms. So the planner is right (these figures are too small to compare). I think the filter step is needed to recheck for invisible tuples. Not sure.